# Question about completeness of the space of bounded linear operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ be a Banach space and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be a normed linear space. Can we say that $(B(X,Y),\|\cdot\|_{\text {op}})$ is Banach?

I know that if $Y$ is Banach then regardless of what the space $X$ is, the space $B(X,Y)$ is necessarily Banach. One of my friends claimed that if $Y$ is not Banach then $B(X,Y)$ cannot be Banach. What he claimed is even much stronger than that. He claimed that $Y$ and $B(X,Y)$ are isometrically isomorphic regardless of the space $X.$ I don't think so because then what is the necessity of $X.$ Can anybody please shed some light on it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Proposition}$. If $B(X,Y) $ is a Banach space (with the operator norm), then $Y$ is also complete.

Proof.  Let $ (y_n)_n \subset Y $ be a Cauchy sequence and let  $ f \in X^* \setminus \{ 0 \}$. For all  $ n \in \mathbb N $, define  $  T_n \colon X \to Y$, by  $ T_n(x) = f(x) y_n $. Then,  $ T_n $ is linear and bounded, for all $  n \in \mathbb N $. To see that it is bounded, notice that
$ || T_n(x)||  = | {f(x)}| \ ||{y_n}|| \leq  ||{f}|| \ ||{y_n}|| \ ||{x}||$, for all $ x \in X $. Moreover, $ || {T_n-T_m} ||= \sup_{x \in B_X} |{f(x)}| \ ||{y_n - y_m}|| \xrightarrow{n.m \to \infty} 0$. Hence,   $ (T_n)_n \subset  B(X,Y) $ is a  Cauchy sequence. By completeness, we can find  $ T \in B(X,Y) $ such that
$ T_n \to  T$ in the operator norm. Pick any  $ x \in X \setminus \ker f $, then  $ T_n(x) \to T(x) $ and thus  $ y_n \to T(x) / |{f(x)}| \in Y $.

$\textbf{EDIT}$: It is true that $B(X,Y)$ is isometric to $Y$. Let $f \in X^*$ with $||f||=1$. Consider the map
$$ Y \ni y \mapsto T_y \ \colon X \to Y ~~~\text{ where } ~~~T_y(x)=f(x) y. $$
This map is linear and for all $y \in Y$, $||T_y|| = \sup_{x \in B_X}|f(x)| \ ||y||= ||y|| \ ||f||=||y||$. In other words, it's a linear isometry.

Comment: One has to exclude the case $X= 0$ in the beginning, in which case $B(X,Y) = 0$ is always complete, whether $Y$ is complete or not.  As for the (good) edit, it is important to note that the image is closed (the argument is similar to the last part of the first proof).

Comment: Yes, the case $X=0$ is trivial indeed